# How to install react-toolbox with Bower

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, bower

The project I'm working on uses bower for all front-end dependency management. I'd like to use `react-toolbox`, but Bower doesn't provide it.

I tried `npm install --save react-toolbox`, but because all of the peer dependencies are installed in `bower_components` rather than `node_modules`, this didn't work.

I then tried `bower install --save https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox.git#1.0.1`. While this did download the package, it didn't build it as there's no `bower.json` associated with the repo.

Finally, I tried re-installing all dependencies with npm, but this led to a lot of problems with module namespacing (this was a surprise to me). Besides, this led to an inflation in the built package size as npm installed multiple versions of many of the common dependencies.

What should my approach be?

Answer (score 0):

This approach didn't answer how to use Bower to install `react-toolbox`, but it did help me continue with my work.

I switched to `webpack` and everything works as expected. I used this tutorial as a starting place https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html.